# The close question dialog is half off screen when called from the flag handling interface

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

The picture below tells the story; that's the whole browser window. There is a vertical scrollbar but no horizontal one. I have this zoomed in (as in, normally, in the browser, it snaps to at 150%), so the width fills the screen (you can see where *Home* is top left), but I think the problem is it is way off center and cannot be moved.<sup>1</sup>

[image]

Notice the moderator flag interface in the bottom third; this happens when that "Close question" button is pressed; if I load the page normally, the normal close button and dialogue work properly.

This is from Google Chrome 76 on GNU/Linux. Here's an view that isn't zoomed which provides a clue about the issue:

[image]

Whereas the base Stack Exchange interface is statically sized, the flag handling interface is dynamically sized and grows to fit regardless of zoom -- i.e., it is not off edge in either picture the way the popup is (it is harder to tell with the first one because there is not the right/left nav bumpers since there are no further flags, but I did double check this).  Possibly the popup, when invoked from that context, uses an incorrect value for the screen geometry.

---

1. I didn't think to try un-zooming (forgot I use it) until I had lost the screen and won't get a chance until there's another flag, but I still think the "way off center" is wrong.

   I also didn't realize it can be moved by mousing over the top area of the popup until informed in comments here.

Comment: Normally, you should be able to move the dialog by dragging the top part with the mouse (on the "Why should this question be closed?" text, for example), although this isn't visually indicated unless the mouse is hovering over that part. Can you verify whether you are unable to move the dialog in this way?

Comment: Okay, deleted my previous comments about it possibly being a touchpad based fiasco as I got a new flag to check with this with.  It definitely starts way off-center.

Comment: @Discrete the “handle” for moving it is very difficult to grab on touch devices. I don’t do review queue stuff at all on my devices because of the lack of “responsiveness” for these dialogs.

Comment: @ColleenV I have been able to repro this on Firefox version 70.0b7. At 100% zoom level, the top left corner of the modal created by the "close question" button in the lower pane is to the left of the viewport, so the modal is partially of the page.

Comment: The culprit seems to be `left: calc(50% - 400px);` in the style of the modal. For the "normal" close button on the page, this is 400px to the left of the center of the screen, as it should be. However, the button in the lower pane creates the modal relative to this pane, where apparently `calc(50%)` does not correspond to the center of the screen, but instead to some position to the left of the center, which results in the modal being created too far to the left of the screen.

Comment: @Discretelizard If you want to post that as an answer, please do -- an explanation of why demonstrates I am not a lunatic and paves the way to a fix, powers-be willing.

Comment: @goldilocks Ok, made an answer. After fiddling a bit with the styling, I'm not sure whether my previous comment describes accurately what is going on. Still, there does seem to be some bug with the use of absolute position and positions relative to that.

Answer (score 5):

Apologies for the long delay in responding. I tried replicating this on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, and it appears this issue is fixed.

Comment: Welcome to the public product team Anita!

Comment: I'm sure I've noticed this still happening in the past week or so, although now I know I can grab at the top it is not such a big deal -- but I'll post a comment here next time (if there is one).

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks for the warm welcome! I'm happy to be here!

Comment: @goldilocks Ping me in the comments if it comes up again

Comment: @AnitaTaylor I think the following report is still an issue which is related to this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353806/the-delete-this-answered-question-dialog-is-not-accessible-on-a-mobile-device

Comment: @KodosJohnson Thanks for bringing that post to my attention. We'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the modal/dialog created from the close question button in the lower pane is positioned too far to the left, even at 100% zoom (on Firefox version 70.0b7):
[image: off center modal]

(As you can see from the content of the modal, I have already closed this question. However, the position is the same as with the normal content of the dialog.)

The left side of the modal is 400 pixels (half the width of the modal) to the left of the dotted line. The dotted line *should* instead be in the center of the screen, which it is when using the normal "close link button" below the post.

A difference between the two modals that could be causing this bug is that the modal from the lower pane is created inside a `<div>` with the `ps-absolute` class. Removing this class from the div positions the modal in the center, although this seems to break other things, so this is probably not the way to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is also a problem when adding to the duplicates list on a question closed as a duplicate. I can’t grab the window to move it.

This screenshot is the entire width of my phone.

> [image: screenshot showing a mostly blank dialog half of the screen]

It’s actually OK until I paste a URL into the box, which shifts it off screen.