# The "Delete this answered question?" dialog is not accessible on a mobile device, making it impossible to delete questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, mobile-web, responsive-design

I'm using the most recent version of the platform using Chrome on my Android device. This behaviour was reproduced on both the main site and on Meta.

When I open one of my questions and click delete, this is what I get:

[image: Can't delete question in Stack]

As you can see, there isn't any way to delete the question.

The only way to go through that is to change Chrome to "Desktop site" mode and then the full message with the delete button will show:

[image: Bug that blocks user from deleting questions]

This problem doesn't happen in answers.

Comment: Yes this needs to be fixed. In the meantime another way to see the delete button is to rotate your device so it's in landscape orientation. Clicking the delete link shows the whole dialog in landscape mode.

Comment: It happen too on moderator action to delete something, answer or question. Switching landscape forth and back do the tip, but it's some work to get the button

Comment: You can't delete answered questions if the answer has an upvote or if there are more than one answer. That box exists but most of the time the result will be "you can't delete this".

Comment: @Catija that's not the problem here. Rather, it's the layout of the box, the button is out of the screen boundary.

Comment: Sure. I'm not arguing that should be fixed. :D My guess is that it's not a "Stacks" box, so it's not conforming to the page width.

Comment: @Catija just clarified because thought you didn't understand it . Could be yes, I didn't check further than what was already reported

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 We've been able to reproduce this and currently have a fix in review to address. Changing to [meta-tag:status-planned] for now and the team will update here once it's addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

I converted this dialog to our new responsive dialog component.